# how to determine in PHP script that the Ajax request is canceled

Tags: php, linux

i have html page, that sends ajax request to php script.
This PHP script run

`exec(COMMAND)`

while COMMAND is executing,  user terminates ajax request.

how to determine  in PHP script that the Ajax request is canceled?

Comment: You can't. If a request is terminated the client just closes the connection. This is handled by the Web server, which in turn is just running the PHP executable. It may terminate PHP or just let it execute and discard the result.

Answer (score 1):

something like ignore_user_abort() will help you.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: In the same direction you can use connection_aborted()
Don't know exactly how would you fit that on your script, but is the way to check if the user disconnected or not. As said above, still the connection is handled by the browser, so the browser may not abort the connection and the process would not see user as disconnected.